# What are some plausible justifications for why "there can be only one" immortal?

Tags: immortality

The *Highlander* series is based on immortals killing each other off so there will be only one immortal in the end. That never sat right with me: why can't the immortals live forever and let live forever?

[image: There can be only one]

What would be the simplest limitation on their magic/immortality that would force them to whittle their numbers down?

(Note that this is not a question about character-motivation. It's about the rules of the world. Yes those rules do drive characters, same as how our social rules drive us, but it's systemic rather than psychological.)

Comment: Question: Are you wanting an answer from the established lore of the Highlander universe? Or are you wanting a hypothetical answer that is similar situation involving immortal beings?

Comment: the latter @TheDemonLord

Comment: In Highlander, there's magic and potentially divine forces at work so anything goes...Furthermore in Highlander it's literally the philosophy, religion, culture, whatever you want to call it and that's all that's required. Just because they say there can only be one doesn't not necessarily make it so.

Comment: Since 100K+ users are answering this question... VTC: (a) Questions about 3rd-party/commercial worlds are off-topic. (b) Brainstorming without providing sufficient restrictions, limitations, expectations, and an explanation for how a best answer will be judged is prohibited.

Answer (score 1):

**the magic  of the world is dying.**

The simplest answer is that the magic of the world (or the plant that make them creat their immortality potion) is fading away. the supply  left  make it so that only one immortal can remain in the world, all of the other will die.

with a small twist, while a great number of immortal could be supplied by that world magic, the less immortal they are, the stronger the immortal who remain her, giving a great incentive

**Rivalry**

another possibility is that the secret to immortality is extremely well preserved. so well preserved that the current immortal won't share it even to his apprentice and if an apprentice manage to become immortal,  they become master and therefore cast shadow on the previous immortal who is forced to fight him to the death to defend his status.